# What is the uses of bool query?

Tags: elasticsearch

Usually I use the query of "AND", "AND NOT", "OR".
Although it seems that a query can be similarly generated by bool query, What kind of case do you use the  "Bool query"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a difference. The keywords "AND", "OR", and "AND NOT" are all just aliases used by Elasticsearch to internally build up a [boolean query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html).

I tend to use boolean queries the long way for a few reasons:

1. That's how I learnt to use them and so I stick with what I know.
2. I can mix and match the kind of clauses I want, the "AND" and "OR" and even the "AND NOT" can all be used in a mix and match fashion.
3. With an explicit [boolean query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) call you can also set the different query types for each one, so one query within the "should" block, which is what "OR" aliases to, could be a [range query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html), whereas the other query could be a regular [term query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html).

Comment: I understand that there is not a difference. Thank you.